# Link for file system to override program requirements

Tags: windows, filesystems

Suppose there are three identical programs arranged for example:

```
1.) C:\Program1\
2.) C:\Program2\
3.) C:\Program3\
```

needed for each database files that are such

```
C:\Program1\Data
C:\Program2\Data
C:\Program3\Data
```

data for the program are identical, it is necessary to do something like shortcuts to the file system to make the Data folder to another location, such as C:\Data\
ie cheat program/filesystem when it refers to.

c:\Program1\Data\somestuff.db it redirects to the c:\Data\somestuff.db

same for Program2 and Program3.

The result should be a single folder with the database for all three programs without modifying program source.

I hope correctly explained, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your looking for Symlinks. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link

Comment: wow, did not think that it is so easy, many thanks!